# Whats wrong in the syntax of my SELECT VBA Statement?

Tags: vb.net

What's wrong in the syntax of

```vb
"SELECT * FROM Tbl_Appointments WHERE Tbl_Appointments.[MRN] = '" & Me.MRN.Value & "' ORDERBY Tbl_Appointments.[Patient_Name];"
```

I keep getting a syntax error.

Btw I am not a professional programmer and I just create little databases for my own use in my clinic, and I didn't get this error earlier.

Comment: Your homework: read up on parameterized queries to avoid **SQL injections** and broken SQL. What do you think happens `Me.MRN.Value` contains single quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDERBY` is incorrect, should be `ORDER BY`